# gradle gradlew flyway to execute multiple tasks, one with stacktrace

Tags: gradle, flyway, gradlew

I have the following two executions:

```
gradlew flywayRepair flywayInfo
gradlew flywayMigrate --stacktrace
```

Is it possible, in one command on execution, to:

1. execute in sequence: flywayRepair, flywayInfo, flywayMigrate
2. only flywayMigrate with --stacktrace?

I suspect this will apply `--stacktrace` to all tasks:

```
gradlew flywayRepair flywayInfo flywayMigrate --stacktrace
```

Comment: The option `--stacktrace` has nothing to do with tasks, it is just an option that tells Gradle to print a (reduced) stacktrace in case of an error. Just run `gradlew flywayRepair flywayInfo flywayMigrate` and add `--stacktrace` once you encounter an error.

Comment: right, that's what I did. Actually stacktrace is fired conditionally in case of error, not like `--debug`, which one would like to have executed only for `flywayMigrate`